# Is it possible for an HDMI cable to be "worn in"?

Tags: cables, video, hdmi

I have an HDMI cable running thirty feet between my computer and a TV. I've had various problems with the screen flashing, stuttering, etcetera, due to the signal not being strong enough to carry a 4K HDR signal over that length. However with two separate cables now, after experiencing those issues initially, they've just gone away over time: initially the screen would go dark every ten to fifteen seconds, then less frequently, and now it doesn't seem to happen at all.

This is challenging my conception of how cables work in general. So, my question is... can a cable be "worn in" by use and carry a signal better over time? Or is there another likely explanation for this behavior?

Comment: I don't think the cable itself, i.e. the copper wires, could exhibit anything associated with "wearing in".  However,I will speculate that the cable connectors might have improved their contacts due to motion from vibration and other movements. Because of the especially long length of your cable, the quality of the connections could be more significant than for a shorter cable.

Comment: Baring high voltage arcing, wires don't change.

Comment: Is it possible that the cable actually got worse, and the PC/HDMI dropped back to 1080p without you noticing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something else must have changed that causes the signal to reach TV better. Maybe TV firmware got updated and new input equalization settings updated with it. Maybe computer video card driver got updated and it uses more drive strength or pre-emphasis for the signal. Maybe some other devices are off so that there is less interference. And thirty feet is on the edge of being able to carry 18 GBPS 4K HDR signals reliably anyway, way more than many devices suggest in their manuals.